# Separate the thread-pool of hazelcast java client

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have an akka application which i should protect my threads from being blocked. So blocking operations should be executed in a separate & dedicated thread-pools. Accessing (Put/Get) hazelcast's IMap is one of these blocking operations (as far as i know, hazelcast does not have reactive java client). In [hazelcast-java-client](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/clients/java) documents it is not clear for me how to separate threads of hazelcast-client from other threads of the application. so my questions are:

1. What is the threading model of hazelcast-java-client?
2. How to make sure all operations are done in a separate thread-pool?
3. What config properties should be considered?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Hazelcast Java client is here.
https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/clients/java#client-system-properties
You can change number of threads etc.

But before doing that I would first use **async** methods of IMap. It provides **lots of** async methods such as

```java
CompletionStage<V> getAsync(@Nonnull K key);
CompletionStage<V> putAsync(@Nonnull K key, @Nonnull V value);
CompletionStage<Void> putAllAsync(@Nonnull Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map);
CompletionStage<Void> setAsync(@Nonnull K key, @Nonnull V value);
...
```

These methods return a **CompletionStage**, so that your akka code does not need to block.

Comment: These `async` methods are async, but not non-blocking.

Comment: It is off-loading the call to the internal thread pool of the hazelcast client. This way it does not block the caller thread.